# How can I solve$\int \sin^3(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to find the integral
$$\int \sin^3xdx\\=
\int \sin^2x \sin xdx\\=
\int (1-\cos^2x) \sin xdx$$

Substitution: $$z=\cos x$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx} = -\sin x$$
$$-dz = \sin x dx$$

Now the above expression would be like this
$$\int -(1-z^2) dz$$
Now integration would be
$$-z + \frac{z^3}{3} + c$$
we replace $z$ by $\cos x$
so our answer would be
$$-\cos x + \frac{\cos^3x}{3} + c$$

But in book this answer is not correct. I want to know the error. Please, can any one solve it and tell me about the error?

Comment: Please format your question using $\LaTeX$ enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: You really ought to use latex for the maths, e.g. type [dollar] \sin ^ 3 (x) [dollar], where [dollar] means the dollar sign.

Comment: can any one help me out to solve the integration of sin^3(x)?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you such a personal question zoonie, but how old are you?

Comment: @zonnie, it isn't nice to ask a further question in the comments without even addressing other comments...

Comment: @zonnie, you will much sooner get an answer if you cooperate with people comenting here.

Comment: sorry. but i got the answer. thanks for you cooperation :)

Comment: Your answer is correct; there is no error. Nice solution, in fact. The answer in the book may have simplified $-\cos x +(\cos^3 x)/3$ further.

Comment: Perhaps they used $\cos^3 x ={\cos(3x)+\cos x\over 4}$ to simplify.

Comment: @zonnie. May be, you could answer the questions you have been asked.

Answer (score 2):

This method looks easier. You can use $\sin3x=3\sin x-4\sin^3x$. Hence you will get $\sin^3x=\frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}$. Hence \begin{align}\int \sin^3(x)dx&=\int \frac{3\sin x-\sin(3x)}{4}\\&= \int \frac{3\sin x}{4}-\int \frac{\sin(3x)}{4}\\&=-\frac{3\cos x}{4}+\frac{\cos(3x)}{12}+c\end{align}

Comment: Why $\sin$ instead of $\cos$?

Comment: Its not like converting sin to cos.This equation i used to convert the third power to unity power,hence only in terms of sin.

Comment: Oh! sorry--I originally thought this was a hint simplify the base.  That's an awesome identity. :)  (+1)

Comment: use euler formula $ 2isin(x)=e^{íx}-e^{-ix} $ plus the binomial theorem